# Rejected URL List in Nutch 1.x

Tags: regex, nutch

I am trying to get a list of all the rejected URLs from `seed.txt` in Nutch 1.x version.

Using the `nutch inject` command, I can get to know the number of URLs being rejected, but is there a way to get the complete list of URLs rejected?

Answer (score 0):

You can check a list of URLs with the command:

```
cat seed_urls.txt | $NUTCH_HOME/bin/nutch filterchecker -stdin
```

Rejected URLs are marked by `-` at the beginning of a line. Of course, you have to run the filterchecker with the same URL filter configuration as the inject command.

Note: that's the command using Nutch 1.14, prior versions require the argument `-allCombined` instead of `-stdin`.